# Magento 2: How can change in the frontend sortOrder of Grand Totals and Tax positions in my account order detail page?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, frontend, sorting, totals

I need to change sort order in order_totals block in the frontend order view page.
I want to swap the position of Grand Total & Tax in order_totals child items.
[image]

Please help to change to order of Tax & Grand Total.

Answer (score 1):

You want to swap the position of `Grand Total` & `Tax`, need to change field in `_initTotals()` function  in `magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php file`.

In `Totals.php` file you can able to find `Total` & `Tax` you can swap here and override `Totals.php` file in your custom module.

**Override `Totals.php` block follow below file path:**

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderView/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_OrderView" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderView/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="Vendor\OrderView\Block\Order\Totals"/>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderView/Block/Order/Totals.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OrderView\Block\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

/**
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
{
    /**
     * Associated array of totals
     * array(
     *  $totalCode => $totalObject
     * )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_totals;

    /**
     * @var Order|null
     */
    protected $_order = null;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize self totals and children blocks totals before html building
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_initTotals();
        foreach ($this->getLayout()->getChildBlocks($this->getNameInLayout()) as $child) {
            if (method_exists($child, 'initTotals') && is_callable([$child, 'initTotals'])) {
                $child->initTotals();
            }
        }
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Get order object
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        if ($this->_order === null) {
            if ($this->hasData('order')) {
                $this->_order = $this->_getData('order');
            } elseif ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order')) {
                $this->_order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
            } elseif ($this->getParentBlock()->getOrder()) {
                $this->_order = $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
            }
        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    /**
     * @param Order $order
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->_order = $order;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totals source object
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getOrder();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        $source = $this->getSource();

        $this->_totals = [];
        $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            ['code' => 'subtotal', 'value' => $source->getSubtotal(), 'label' => __('Subtotal')]
        );

        $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'grand_total',
                'field' => 'grand_total',
                'strong' => true,
                'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
                'label' => __('Grand Total'),
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Add shipping
         */
        if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
            $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'shipping',
                    'field' => 'shipping_amount',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                    'label' => __('Shipping & Handling'),
                ]
            );
        }

        /**
         * Add discount
         */
        if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0) {
            if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
            } else {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount');
            }
            $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'discount',
                    'field' => 'discount_amount',
                    'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                    'label' => $discountLabel,
                ]
            );
        }

        /**
         * Base grandtotal
         */
        if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
            $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                    'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total to be Charged'),
                    'is_formated' => true,
                ]
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add new total to totals array after specific total or before last total by default
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $total
     * @param   null|string $after
     * @return  $this
     */
    public function addTotal(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $total, $after = null)
    {
        if ($after !== null && $after != 'last' && $after != 'first') {
            $totals = [];
            $added = false;
            foreach ($this->_totals as $code => $item) {
                $totals[$code] = $item;
                if ($code == $after) {
                    $added = true;
                    $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
                }
            }
            if (!$added) {
                $last = array_pop($totals);
                $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
                $totals[$last->getCode()] = $last;
            }
            $this->_totals = $totals;
        } elseif ($after == 'last') {
            $this->_totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
        } elseif ($after == 'first') {
            $totals = [$total->getCode() => $total];
            $this->_totals = array_merge($totals, $this->_totals);
        } else {
            $last = array_pop($this->_totals);
            $this->_totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
            $this->_totals[$last->getCode()] = $last;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add new total to totals array before specific total or after first total by default
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $total
     * @param   null|string $before
     * @return  $this
     */
    public function addTotalBefore(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $total, $before = null)
    {
        if ($before !== null) {
            if (!is_array($before)) {
                $before = [$before];
            }
            foreach ($before as $beforeTotals) {
                if (isset($this->_totals[$beforeTotals])) {
                    $totals = [];
                    foreach ($this->_totals as $code => $item) {
                        if ($code == $beforeTotals) {
                            $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
                        }
                        $totals[$code] = $item;
                    }
                    $this->_totals = $totals;
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        $totals = [];
        $first = array_shift($this->_totals);
        $totals[$first->getCode()] = $first;
        $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
        foreach ($this->_totals as $code => $item) {
            $totals[$code] = $item;
        }
        $this->_totals = $totals;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Total object by code
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTotal($code)
    {
        if (isset($this->_totals[$code])) {
            return $this->_totals[$code];
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Delete total by specific
     *
     * @param   string $code
     * @return  $this
     */
    public function removeTotal($code)
    {
        unset($this->_totals[$code]);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Apply sort orders to totals array.
     * Array should have next structure
     * array(
     *  $totalCode => $totalSortOrder
     * )
     *
     *
     * @param   array $order
     * @return  $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function applySortOrder($order)
    {
        \uksort(
            $this->_totals,
            function ($code1, $code2) use ($order) {
                return ($order[$code1] ?? 0) <=> ($order[$code2] ?? 0);
            }
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get totals array for visualization
     *
     * @param array|null $area
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTotals($area = null)
    {
        $totals = [];
        if ($area === null) {
            $totals = $this->_totals;
        } else {
            $area = (string)$area;
            foreach ($this->_totals as $total) {
                $totalArea = (string)$total->getArea();
                if ($totalArea == $area) {
                    $totals[] = $total;
                }
            }
        }
        return $totals;
    }

    /**
     * Format total value based on order currency
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $total
     * @return  string
     */
    public function formatValue($total)
    {
        if (!$total->getIsFormated()) {
            return $this->getOrder()->formatPrice($total->getValue());
        }
        return $total->getValue();
    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: That's working but here one problem occured. When override the Block then Subtotal Include shipping feature not working. How can this manage?

Comment: Share your overrided code so I can check what have you done for override ?

Comment: Please refer the below override method:

protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $source = $this->getSource();

        $this->_totals['tax_amount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'tax_amount',
                'field' => 'tax_amount',
                'strong' => false,
                'value' => $source->getTaxAmount(),
                'label' => __('Includes %1 GST','7%'),
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have override the Totals.php block.
Working fine for me. Follow my updated answers file path and check.